# Moving a hard disk with PostgreSQL data folder to another server

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm running a NAS server with an SD card mounted as `/` and RAID-1 storage mounted under `/media/hdd`.  `/etc` folder is on SD card.  PostgreSQL data folder is on the RAID-1 disk.

```
/-+
  +- etc
  |  +- postgres
  |     +- 10
  |        +- mycluster 
  |
  +- media
     |
     +- hdd
        +- pgsql
           +- data
              +- mycluster
```

If I want to move RAID-1 disks to a different box, what is the correct way to re-create a PostgreSQL cluster using exiting data folder?  Let's assume I stopped the cluster, shutdown the system, took out hard disks and attached them to another box.  Can I create a new cluster on that box using the existing data folder on the attached hard disks?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is no problem, as long as

- you are using the same major version of PostgreSQL on the new machine
- PostgreSQL was built in the same way
- both machines have the same architecture and operating system version (the version is relevant because it might affect the collations, changing versions requires a `REINDEX`)

Running PostgreSQL on a NAS file system is dangerous, because many NAS implementations are not reliable.

Comment: What is the correct way to do that? when I run ```sudo pg_createcluster 10 mycluster -d /media/hdd/mycloud/pgsql/mycluster``` I get ```Configuring already existing cluster (configuration: /etc/postgresql/10/mycluster, data: /media/hdd/mycloud/pgsql/mycluster, owner: 110:115)
Error: move_conffile: required configuration file /media/hdd/mycloud/pgsql/mycluster/postgresql.conf does not exist```

Comment: Looks like the dreaded Debian packages. Just create a new cluster (with the same major version), stop the server, remove the data directory, replace it with your data directory, replace the configuration files (which are somewhere under `/etc` on Debian) and start the server.

Comment: Thank you, it worked!